# What does this variable declaration form mean?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It is that situation, when you get some code, which works, but you don't know how.
What does this declaration method do?

```
const { actions: { createRole, updateRole } = {} } = props;
```

Comment: This is called [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: The destructuring is pointed out. But what does the inner '= {}' do? It's probably some sort of default assignment, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I have since figured it out, it is to prevent a typeError if props.actions is undefined, it will assign an empty object to call createRole on.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code uses destructing for an nested object. The following example might help for understanding this new JavaScript syntax (has been introduced with ES6):

```
const user = {
  id: 339,
  name: 'Fred',
  age: 42,
  education: {
    degree: 'Masters'
  }
};
const {education: {degree}} = user;
console.log(degree); //prints: Masters
```

I would recommend the following resource for further examples:
https://medium.com/@pyrolistical/destructuring-nested-objects-9dabdd01a3b8